# Selected value in ComboBox is not inserted correctly into cell

Tags: excel, vba

I have the following Excel spreadsheet:

```
       A          B
1    ComboBox1
2      1.000
3     10.000
4    100.000
5
```

This list is loaded into a `ComboBox` using the following VBA:

```
Sub UserForm_Activate()
    Dim myArr As Variant
    Dim myRng As Range

    Set myRng = Sheet1.Range("A2:A4")
    ReDim myArr(myRng.Cells.Count)

    Dim i As Long
    For i = LBound(myArr) To UBound(myArr)
        myArr(i) = Format(myRng.Cells(i + 1), "#,##")
    Next i

    ComboBox1.List = myArr
End Sub
```

This VBA is needed to have the thousands seperator within the `ComboBox`.

All this works fine so far.

---

Now I want to insert the selected value from the `ComboBox` into **Cell B1**:

```
Sub ComboBox1_Change()
    Sheet1.Range("B1").Value = ComboBox1.Value
End Sub
```

Unfortunately, this VBA does not insert the value I selected in the `ComboBox`. It always cuts the last three `0` so when I select `1.000` in the ComboBox in **Cell B1** the value `1` is inserted, instead of `10.000` the value `10` is inserted and so on.

I guess the issue is resulting from formatting with the `"#,##"` in the VBA code for the `ComboBox` but I could not find a solution yet to keep the thousands sperator in the `ComboBox` and insert the correct value in **Cell B1**.

Do you have any idea how I can solve this issue?

Comment: It is inserting it as a number and as such it is subject to the number format of the cell in which the number is being placed.  Format the cell with the desired display.

Comment: @ScottCraner - passing `2.000` to a cell in Excel would always result in `2` and not `2000`. Like - `Range("A1") = 2.000`. If the OP decides to increase the zeroes shown, it could be `2.000`, but this is still `2`.

Comment: Ah so, this is a local setting thing, I misunderstood, I thought it was a display issue with decimals, but in fact the `.` is the thousand separator not the decimal separator.  @Vityata

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`10.000` is understood as `10,000` in Excel, thus the last trailing zeroes are removed automatically. To make sure that you get what you want, the best way is to remove the `.` from the `Combobox1` and to pass it to Excel:

```
Range("B1") = Replace(ComboBox1, ".", "")
```

There is an option to pass the `2.000` in text format in Excel:

```
Range("B1") = ComboBox1
```